# Capturing get parameter value

Tags: ruby, regex, getparameter

How can I extract a param value using a regex, like the mver param from this string:

> "/maze/action.xml?mver=66381&cid=474&melu=0&osName=Windows%208&dbv=38&ucnt=19"

I want to extract the mver param using

> mver\=(.*?)\&

How can I make it capture it even if it's the last param (no trailing ampersand)

Thank you

Comment: FYI added online demo to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way for this -

```
2.1.0 :001 > require 'uri'
 => true 
2.1.0 :002 > uri = URI("/maze/action.xml?mver=66381&cid=474&melu=0&osName=Windows%208&dbv=38&ucnt=19")
 => #<URI::Generic:0x00000103011c98 URL:/maze/action.xml?mver=66381&cid=474&melu=0&osName=Windows%208&dbv=38&ucnt=19> 
2.1.0 :003 > require 'cgi'
 => true 
2.1.0 :004 > CGI::parse(uri.query)
 => {"mver"=>["66381"], "cid"=>["474"], "melu"=>["0"], "osName"=>["Windows 8"], "dbv"=>["38"], "ucnt"=>["19"]} 
2.1.0 :005 > CGI::parse(uri.query)['mver']
 => ["66381"] 
2.1.0 :006 >
```

Have a look at [`CGI::parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-parse) and [this example](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#module-URI-label-Basic+example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby 2 and the parameter is all digits, this short regex is all you need:

```
mver=\K\d+
```

(No capturing groups needed, the regex matches the digits directly).

If the parameter can contain other characters than digits, then you can use this variation:

```
mver=\K\[^&]+
```

See online [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mH9aT2)

**How does it work?**

1. We match the literal `mver=`
2. `\K` tells the engine to drop what we have matched so far, i.e. `mver=`, from the string that will be returned
3. We match any number of digits. These digits will be the final match to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex:
if you want to capture both param and value.

```
mver=(((?!&).)*)
```

for only value.

```
(?<=mver=)(((?!&).)*)
```